# How to pass arguments dynamically to filter function in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a employees file which have data as below:

```
Name:   Age:
David   25
Jag     32
Paul    33
Sam     18
```

Which I loaded into `dataframe` in Apache Spark and I am filtering the values as below:

```py
employee_rdd=sc.textFile("employee.txt")
employee_df=employee_rdd.toDF()
employee_data = employee_df.filter("Name = 'David'").collect()
```

```
+-----------------+-------+
|            Name:|   Age:|
+-----------------+-------+
|David            |25     |
+-----------------+-------+
```

But when I am trying to do something like this:

`emp_Name='Sam'` and passing this Name to filter like below:

```
employee_data = employee_df.filter("Name = 'emp_Name'").collect
```

but this is giving me empty list.

Comment: relevant answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813272/pyspark-dataframe-how-to-pass-string-variable-to-df-where-condition?rq=1

Comment: Relavant answers is already explained in the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813272/pyspark-dataframe-how-to-pass-string-variable-to-df-where-condition?rq=1

Comment: @Mohan Kumar Kannan This does not work. Can u show with a where clause example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done in scala you can change it to python

```
val emp_name = "Sam"

val employee_data = employee_df.filter(col("Name") === emp_name)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
emp_Name='Sam'
employee_data = employee_df.filter(employee_df["Name"] == emp_Name).collect()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
filter_condition= col("Name").isin(["Sam","John"])
employee_data = employee_df.filter(filter_condition).collect
```

Comment: The question is about how to use a variable in the filter condition.